# Building a Crystal Radio Questions

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, oscillators, crystals, radio-frequency

I have been reading several books and articles about building a crystal radio and the explanations about the inner workings of the circuit seem vague. All articles and books mention the coil and the capacitor in the circuit, which I still don't know what it is they do. It is mentioned how the coil, depending on the windings, will only receive a certain type of electromagnetic waveform, how is this possible? What does the amount of windings in the coil have to do with the type of waveform? Additionally, how exactly does the capacitor work to only grab certain frequencies?

Several questions in one but this is very troublesome and can't find answers anywhere. Thanks to all who contribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The coil is an inductor, which stores energy in a magnetic field. The coil & capacitor together form a basic electronic oscillator.

If you start out with a charged capacitor, it will start to discharge, forcing a current through the coil. This will set up a magnetic field in the coil, which takes up some of the energy that used to be stored in the capacitor. When the capacitor has discharged, and is no longer forcing a current, then magnetic field starts to collapse. This causes the coil to induce (hence the name *inductor*) a current in the circuit in the same direction, which keeps charge flowing to the other side of the capacitor. Once the inductor has fully discharged, the capacitor is charged again, but to the opposite of its original polarity, and the cycle starts over, in reverse.

The natural frequency of this oscillator depends on the size of the capacitor and the size of the inductor. Thus, changing the number of coils will change the circuits inductance which changes the natural frequency.

When you add in an antenna to collect radio waves, the radio waves will drive the oscillation of the circuit at their own frequency. For a wave whose frequency is very close to the natural frequency of the oscillator, each cycle of the radio wave will drive the oscillator in the same direction, and they'll constructively interfere, adding more energy to the oscillator on each cycle. Waves whose frequencies *don't* match up with the natural frequency of the oscillator circuit will, however, destructively interfere.

It's like pushing a swing- if you always push back when it reaches its highest height, then you keep it going and push it higher and higher. If, however, you push on it halfway through a swing, or at random intervals, then it becomes erratic and doesn't go much of anywhere.

So, by changing the number of windings in the coil, you tune it to amplify different frequencies of radio waves, which determines what the radio picks up for you to hear. Other frequencies are not amplified, so you don't hear them.

Comment: you sir, have provided one of the most intuitive answers I have, when are you going to write your own book so I can buy it? I can now understand why the circuit is called an oscillator... Best of all, why the circuit doesn't repond to just any electromagnetic frequency. I really appreciate your answer.